# Ошибка JS: TypeError: Electron.inita is not a constructor

Tags: javascript

Выдает такого рода ошибку. Погуглил, узнал, что она возникает когда пытаешься вызвать функцию как конструктор, но это не конструктор.

Но это не так в данном случаи. Что я делаю не так?

> TypeError: Electron.inita is not a constructor

```js
;
(function() {
  var arbitals = document.querySelectorAll('.animate-electron__arbital');

  function randomNumInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }

  function addElectrons(electronCount, arbitals, arbitalNum, startCardinats) {
    var electron = document.createElement('div');
    electron.classList.add('animate-electron__electron');
    electron.style.width = randomNumInt(45, 55) + 'px';
    var electronWidth = getComputedStyle(electron).width;
    electron.style.height = electronWidth;
    arbitals[arbitalNum].appendChild(electron);
  }

  function Electron() {
    this.degrees = randomNumInt(0, 20);
    this.arbital = arbitals[randomNumInt(0, 3)];
    this.item = document.createElement('div');

    this.itemCreate = function() {
      this.item.classList.add('animate-electron__electron');
      this.item.style.width = randomNumInt(45, 55) + 'px';
      var electronWidth = getComputedStyle(this.item).width;
      this.item.style.height = electronWidth;
      this.arbital.appendChild(this.item);
    }

    this.itemRun = function() {
      var diametr = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this.arbital).width);

      this.item.style.right = diametr / 2 - Math.cos(this.degrees) * diametr / 2 + 'px';
      this.item.style.bottom = diametr / 2 - Math.sin(this.degrees) * diametr / 2 + 'px';

      var moving = setInterval(function() {
        this.degrees += 0.2;
        this.item.style.right = diametr / 2 - Math.cos(this.degrees) * diametr / 2 + 'px';
        this.item.style.bottom = diametr / 2 - Math.sin(this.degrees) * diametr / 2 + 'px';

      }.bind(this), 500)
    }

    this.inita = function() {
      this.itemCreate();
      this.itemRun();
    }
  }

  new Electron.inita();

}())
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


/*Header*/

.header {
  height: 79px;
}

.top-menu {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 30px 0;
  padding-left: 80px;
}

.top-menu__item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 46px;
}

.top-menu__link {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #475055;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.top-menu__link:hover {
  color: #56ccc8;
}

.left-menu-button {
  background-color: #56ccc8;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left-menu-button:hover .left-menu-button__row:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.left-menu-button__icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.left-menu-button__row {
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.left-menu-button__row:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: .3s;
}

.left-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  width: 300px;
  height: calc(100% - 79px);
  background-color: white;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: 100;
}

.left-menu--active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.left-menu h2 {
  color: #475055;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 30px 0;
  margin-left: 16px;
  display: block;
}

.left-menu__list {
  list-style: none;
}

.left-menu__item {}

.left-menu__link {
  padding: 16px;
  display: block;
  color: #475055;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e5e7;
  transition: .3s;
}

.left-menu__link:hover {
  background-color: #56ccc8;
  color: #fff;
}


/*Main section*/

.main {
  height: calc(100vh - 79px);
  background-color: #c5cdd1;
  position: relative;
}

.game-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 65%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.game-block:first-child {
  background-color: #81ecec;
  left: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.game-block:last-child {
  background-color: #00cec9;
  right: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.animate-electron {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
  perspective: 600px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.animate-electron:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.animate-electron__core {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #56ccc8;
  animation: coreAnimation 3s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes coreAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -60%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

.animate-electron__arbitals {}

.animate-electron__arbital {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid #56ccc8;
  transform-style: flat;
}

.animate-electron__arbital:first-child {
  transform: rotateY(70deg) rotateZ(20deg);
}

.animate-electron__arbital:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(60deg) rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(-30deg);
}

.animate-electron__arbital:last-child {
  transform: rotateY(-60deg) rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(100deg);
}

.animate-electron__electron {
  background-color: #b2bec3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="top-menu">
    <div class="left-menu-button">
      <div class="left-menu-button__icon">
        <div class="left-menu-button__row"></div>
        <div class="left-menu-button__row"></div>
        <div class="left-menu-button__row"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="top-menu__navigation">
      <ul class="top-menu__list">
        <li class="top-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li class="top-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Источники</a>
        </li>
        <li class="top-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Правила игр</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <nav class="left-menu">
    <h2>Игры</h2>
    <div class="left-menu__item">
      <a href="#" class="left-menu__link">Электрон</a>
    </div>
    <div class="left-menu__item">
      <a href="#" class="left-menu__link">Лаборатория</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<main class="main">
  <a href="#" class="game-block">
    <div class="animate-electron">
      <div class="animate-electron__arbitals">
        <div class="animate-electron__arbital"></div>
        <div class="animate-electron__arbital"></div>
        <div class="animate-electron__arbital"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="animate-electron__core"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="game-block"></a>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данное выражение

```
new Electron.inita();
```

рассматривается как `new (Electron.inita)();`, то есть сначала идет попытка получить свойство `inita` и лишь затем использование его как конструктора.

Так как у функции `Electron` нет такого свойства - получается закономерная ошибка.

Воспроизвести можно простым примером:

```js
function A() {}

new A.a();
```

Чтобы появилось это свойство, в качестве конструктора нужно вызывать функцию `Electron`:

```
new Electron().inita()
```

либо обрамить скобками: `(new Electron).inita()`

```js
function A() {
  this.a = function() {
    console.log('a')
  }
}

new A().a();
(new A).a();
```